# iOS: ios 11 UITableView behaviour changed

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In iOS 11 This is a pretty big change in behaviour of UITableview and existing code/or below iOS11 may work differently.
When i insert data in tableview row, row behaves weird like jumping or scrolling up and down.

Comment: What is the issue are you getting?

Comment: Code not found : Error 404

Comment: Plz screenshot ?

Comment: @Yatendra: can not provide the screenshot

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my issue:
In iOS 11, UITableView uses estimated heights by default. This is a big change in behaviour and existing code may work differently. Just put 0 to tableview property estimatedRowHeight.

```
yourTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 0.0
```